# Powershell Administrator Permission Denied when modifying the UAC

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to modify the permissions of the UAC with a powershell script that looks like:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs Administrator

Set-ItemProperty -Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA -Value 0

$UAC = Get-ItemProperty -Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system -Name EnableLUA
$UAC.EnableLUA
```

Even though I am running the script as administrator, I still get the following error:

> Set-ItemProperty : Requested registry access is not allowed. At
>   C:\Users\Bert\Desktop\autoLims.ps1:8 char:17
>   + Set-ItemProperty <<<<  -Path registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\policies\system
>   -Name EnableLUA -Value 0
>       + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...policies\system:String) [Set-ItemProperty],
>   SecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

Any ideas why it wont run the script even though I am running the script as administrator? Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: I think you want just `-Verb runAs` -- no `Administrator`

Comment: If you want to make that an answer, I'll give you the points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-Verb` parameter only takes **one** argument e.g. `print`. In the case of elevation it will be `RunAs` which will run the process with the current user's full privileges.

---

From the [Start-Process documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849848.aspx):

```
-Verb <String>
```

Specifies a verb to use when starting the process. The verbs that are available are determined by the file name extension of the file that runs in the process.

The following table shows the verbs for some common process file types.

```
File type  Verbs
---------  -------
.cmd       Edit, Open, Print, Runas
.exe       Open, RunAs
.txt       Open, Print, PrintTo
.wav       Open, Play
```

To find the verbs that can be used with the file that runs in a process, use the `New-Object` cmdlet to create a `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` object for the file. The available verbs are in the Verbs property of the `ProcessStartInfo` object.